# Python | Selenium | Keeps outputting page source rather than what I see when I manually inspect element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, beautifulsoup

I expect to print out what I see when I manually inspect the page. However, it seems like it's printing the page source because I can't find elements that are there when I manually inspect.

I'm trying to get the product names for Bank of America's credit cards.

I'm using Selenium because the product names on the bankofamerica site are generated via Javascript. Once I know that I'm parsing the right elements, I plan to find the card names and other related elements by searching for the class.

I believe that I've properly installed the Firefox web driver because the code opens a browser window to the correct page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.bankofamerica.com/credit-cards/#filter')
html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

sel_soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print (sel_soup)
```

Comment: you are not filtering the parsed html with the required xpath, that's the reason why it's showing the entire html.

Comment: @supputuri Thank you very much for your help. And apologies if I'm still missing something, but at this stage, I expect it to output the entire html. But it isn't outputting the same html that I see if I inspect the page manually, rather it is outputting the static source of the page (not the dynamic elements that the Javascript is outputting). Does this help clarify?

Comment: you mean to say the meta data or the dynamic data that will be loaded as you keep scrolling the page? I would suggest using the selenium to get your desired result in your case, as there is a js which is loading the data and BS will get the html without js data.

Comment: The dynamic data that is loaded as you scroll the page. Specifically, if I manually inspect the page I can find the class="small-12 medium-9 columns" which contains the info I need, but when I run the code that I posted above 'class="small-12 medium-9 columns" ' doesn't show up anywhere. Thanks :)

Ah, I just read your second part, I'll work on replacing BeautifulSoup with something else related to selenium. Just need to figure out what that should be... :)

Comment: Just posted the pseudo code, that should give you good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code using selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.bankofamerica.com/credit-cards/#filter')
# wait until the `.small-12.medium-9.columns` class elements present
WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.small-12.medium-9.columns')))
# get all the elements with matching class
creditCardOptions = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.small-12.medium-9.columns')
# now you can have your own logic to iterate through all the CC options.
```